# PHP compare login details

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a strange error in my PHP code. I want to compare my username and password. When I echo out the form then there are the right values and when I change `$username` and `$password` in the `$sql` variable it works fine.

It gets the right variables, but it doesn't accept them.

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
   <tr>
      <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
         <td>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td width="78">Username</td>
                  <td width="6">:</td>
                  <td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Password</td>
                  <td>:</td>
                  <td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
      </form>
   </tr>
</table>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $username = $_POST['myusername'];
    $password = $_POST['mypassword'];
    echo $username;
    echo $password;
    include "connect.php";
    $sql="SELECT * FROM access WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo $count;
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1){
        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
        session_register("myusername");
        session_register("mypassword"); 
        header("location:login_success.php");
    } else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
}
?>
```

PS

I know there is no encryption whatsoever, but I wanted to have this working first.

Comment: You do know, [`session_register` has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0](http://us1.php.net/session_register) and the query really is the problem here?

Comment: looks correct. maybe you don't have this user in table, or you are missing capital letters ?

Comment: any error are u getting ? USE if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
to see if there is something obvious

Comment: More importantly...why in the world are you storing a username and password to a session? You should instead check if the credentials match and store a `logged_in` flag to the session

Comment: I'm just going to throw in here that your code is in serious risk of injection attacks.

Comment: @JaredEitnier depending on the project this could make sense (if OP needs username and password for following requests e.g.)

Comment: Try changing your `mysql_query` statement to this: `$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` -- if there are any SQL errors, it will tell you and kill the script.

Comment: @kingkero then he should securely poll the database for it as needed

Comment: @josh - true but at this time I won't bother. First sin: storing password in not hashed form, second one - allowing sql injection,third    storing password in session, fourth not checking the mysql errors

If guy is learning he will get all this things after some time.

Comment: @JaredEitnier Still, with no other insecure code, a session should be safe though?

Comment: Thanks for all your ideas. The reason why I use this is because it is not for commercial uses or anything like that. It is to be used local. I am going to prevent SQL Injection later on, though. For now I want this working as main priority.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what happens this will not work:

```
header("location:login_success.php");
```

because you have HTML before it... you have to have all `header()` before any html gets printed out. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

To fix this, put your PHP block of code, before the HTML block of code, like this. (make sure there is no whitespace before `<?php`, because that will render `header()` useless.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $username = $_POST['myusername'];
    $password = $_POST['mypassword'];
    echo $username;
    echo $password;
    include "connect.php";
    $sql="SELECT * FROM access WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo $count;
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1){
        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
        session_register("myusername");
        session_register("mypassword"); 
        header("location:login_success.php");
    } else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
}
?>
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
   <tr>
      <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
         <td>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td width="78">Username</td>
                  <td width="6">:</td>
                  <td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Password</td>
                  <td>:</td>
                  <td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
      </form>
   </tr>
</table>
```

---

Another thing that people keep bring up is SQL Injection. This is how you could use `mysqli`. (Don't forget your connection needs to be using mysqli)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM access WHERE username = ? and password= ?";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $count = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();

    echo $count;
}else die("Failed to prepare!");
```

which would replace this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM access WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $count;
```

Comment: Thank for your respond.
I tried your suggestion, but still no result. I still get 0 matches in my mySQL table.